# Is there a way to get the type name of a trait?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use `std::intrinsics::type_name` to get the type name of a trait but can't compile it:

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

use std::intrinsics::type_name;

trait TestTrait: Sized {
    fn test(&self);
}

struct MyStruct {}

struct GetType {}

impl GetType {
    fn test_type<T: ?Sized>() {
        let test = unsafe { type_name::<T>() };
        println!("{:?}", test);
    }
}

fn main() {
    GetType::test_type::<i32>();
    GetType::test_type::<MyStruct>();
    GetType::test_type::<TestTrait>();
}
```

Here is the error I get from the compiler

```
error[E0038]: the trait `TestTrait` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:23:30
   |
23 |         GetType::test_type::<TestTrait>();
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TestTrait` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

Here is the output of that test when I comment the line `GetType::test_type::<TestTrait>();`

```
"i32"
"MyStruct"
```

Is there a way to solve this or to get the type name of a trait?

---

Working solution thanks to @evotopid

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

use std::intrinsics::type_name;

trait TestTrait { // <--- remove `: Sized` constraint from here 
    fn test(&self);
}

struct MyStruct {}

struct GetType {}

impl GetType {
    fn test_type<T: ?Sized>() { // <--- trick is in that bound
        let test = unsafe { type_name::<T>() };
        println!("{:?}", test);
    }
}

fn main() {
    GetType::test_type::<i32>();
    GetType::test_type::<MyStruct>();
    GetType::test_type::<TestTrait>();
}
```

Leading to the following output

```
"i32"
"MyStruct"
"TestTrait"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually [explained in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#the-trait-cannot-require-self-sized) pretty well:

> Generally, `Self : Sized` is used to indicate that the trait should not be used as a trait object. If the trait comes from your own crate, consider removing this restriction.

If you want to use trait objects, which I guess you want, because otherwise it would not make sense to get the name of a trait, you have to remove the `Sized` constraint from your trait definition.

That being said, are you sure you need intrinsics? Most likely there is a better way, which would also allow you to use stable Rust in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @evotopid. If I remove the `Sized` constraint, I still can't get `GetType::test_type::<TestTrait>();` to compile (see my updated post for the compilation error message).

The only way to work around that is to call `GetType::test_type::<Box<TestTrait>>();` which is quite cumbersome (I could still parse the string to get what I want but the call is somewhat weird)

I want to get the trait name as a String to be then used in a map, not as a trait object. I read the warning about intrinsics but couldn't find another way to get that

Comment: This seems to be working? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8b8220dc22bfb9ffc070ac9c6748d38e&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Comment: Indeed, I needed to add a `<T: ?Sized>` constraint to the `test_type()` function. Great catch, thanks
(editing my original question for readers)